# Monitor sub process created from a shell command in windows

Tags: python, windows, shell, subprocess

I am opening a program using `subprocess.Popen`

`import subprocess`

`prog = subprocess.Popen(['myprog', args], shell=True)`

I want to monitor the process 'myprog' and wait untill it terminates before my code continues.

The problem which I am facing is `prog.pid` is the PID of the shell and not 'myprog' and I have no idea how to obtain the PID of 'myprog'. I tried to use `psutil` to find the child processes of `prog.pid`:

`parent = psutil.Process(prog.pid)`
`children = parent.children(recursive=True)`

but an empty list is returned.

Unfortunately I am not able to start 'myprog' without the shell. When I run the command with `shell=False` I receive the following error message:
`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

I have search the web high and low but all promising leads are for non-Windows users.

Comment: are you sure you cannot make your program without the shell? Can you explain why in your question? maybe with the actual command line. Because that is fixable.

Comment: I am trying to open Atom with the command `atom path\to\file\to\open`

Comment: and can you type `where atom` ? we're going somewhere here.

Comment: Yes I can. The output is at C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\atom\bin with 2 files `atom` and `atom.cmd`

Answer (score 1):

Your `atom` command is probably a `.cmd` file which launches an executable, which explains the need for `shell=True`

You won't go to the extend of re-coding the .bat file in python, BUT you don't need the executable PID either.

If the executable ends, the batch file ends, so forget about monitoring `prog.pid`, just monitor `prog` using `poll` (in the same python script of course).

The `poll` method allows to check if the process has ended (if it has, it returns the exit code, if it hasn't it returns `None`), and this is non-blocking so you could do that anytime you want:

```
if prog.poll() is not None:
    # process has ended
    print("ended")
```

Let's remind the blocking wait of doing that:

```
return_code = prog.wait()
```

But in your case, the `atom.cmd` command seems to start the process in background, making it impossible to monitor without the PID.

A workaround in that case is to make a copy of `atom.cmd`, remove the `start` prefix to run the executable in foreground and run the copy instead.

(or since the `cmd` calls another `atom.cmd` file as you commented, locate the file `app-1.13.0\resources\cli\atom.cmd` from `atom.cmd` original directory and remove the `start` prefix there)

Comment: I have tried to use `prog.poll` and `prog.wait()` but it terminates fairly quickly which promoted me to believe that I am monitoring the shell instead of the 'myprog'

Comment: I opened the atom.cmd file in a text editor and this is the content: line 1`@echo off`  
line 2`"%~dp0\..\app-1.13.0\resources\cli\atom.cmd" %*`. I don't see the start prefix

Comment: Not that it changes this problem, but `Popen` actually doesn't require `shell=True` to run a .cmd or .bat file. However, you have to use the full name with the extension, since ".EXE" is the only extension the underlying `CreateProcess` call tries to append.

Comment: @EDWhyte see my edit. Try to remove `start` on the other `atom.cmd` file.